# Return all alarms from AWS instead of only 50 using describe_alarms on Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

How can I print all the alarms names, instead of only 50, when using the function describe_alarms?

Code, using Python:

```
conn = boto.connect_cloudwatch()
alarms = conn.describe_alarms()    
for item in alarms:
    print item.name
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default it returns 50. If you want more, set **max_records=value** and try.

Due to underlying AWS API implementation restriction, it will return a maximum of 100 alarms. Don't know if it is fixed now.

conn.describe_alarms(max_records=100)

> Help on method describe_alarms in module boto.ec2.cloudwatch:
>
> describe_alarms(self, action_prefix=None, alarm_name_prefix=None,
>   alarm_names=None, max_records=None, state_value=None, next_token=None)
>
> ```
> :type max_records: int
> :param max_records: The maximum number of alarm descriptions
>     to retrieve.
> ```

Comment: Hi. The attribute max_records still return a maximum of 100 alarms. Is it possible to return more then 100, maybe using next_token?

Comment: No. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeAlarms.html
allows a maximum of 100 records and  boto uses AWS APIs.

Comment: in boto3 the param has changed: c.describe_alarms(MaxRecords=100)

Answer (score 5):

Even though I am a bit late to the party, here is my solution (in Java). You have to get the next token and keep on asking for the Result in a loop until there is no next token, so it behaves like a pagination on a website

```
String nextToken = null;
List<MetricAlarm> metricAlarms = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

    DescribeAlarmsRequest describeAlarmsRequest = new DescribeAlarmsRequest();
    describeAlarmsRequest.setNextToken(nextToken);
    describeAlarmsRequest.setMaxRecords(100);

    DescribeAlarmsResult describeAlarmsResult = getClient().describeAlarms(describeAlarmsRequest);
    List<MetricAlarm> metricAlarmsTmp = describeAlarmsResult.getMetricAlarms();
    metricAlarms.addAll(metricAlarmsTmp);
    nextToken = describeAlarmsResult.getNextToken();
    logger.info("nextToken: {}", nextToken);

    if (nextToken == null) {
        break;
    }
}
logger.info("metricAlarms size: {}", metricAlarms.size());
```

Of course there is room for improvement, e.g. create a while loop instead of a for loop.

**UPDATE:**

Here my refined version

```
String nextToken = null;
List<MetricAlarm> metricAlarms = new ArrayList<>();

while (nextToken != null || metricAlarms.size() == 0) {
    DescribeAlarmsRequest describeAlarmsRequest = new DescribeAlarmsRequest().withNextToken(nextToken).withMaxRecords(100); // create the request
    DescribeAlarmsResult describeAlarmsResult = getClient().describeAlarms(describeAlarmsRequest); // get the result
    metricAlarms.addAll(describeAlarmsResult.getMetricAlarms()); // add new alarms to our list
    nextToken = describeAlarmsResult.getNextToken(); // check if we have a nextToken
    if (nextToken == null && cachedMetricAlarms.size() == 0) { // if we have no alarm in AWS we get inside the loop but we would never exit -> intercept that
            break;
        }
}
logger.info("metricAlarms size: {}", metricAlarms.size());
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a complete example of how to paginate through the records in order to guarantee that you retrieve all of the records rather then being limited by the max records on the Cloudwatch Alarms API:

```
alarmMaxRecords = 10

response = client.describe_alarms(
AlarmNamePrefix=prefix,
MaxRecords=alarmMaxRecords
)

alarmsItems = []
while response:
    alarmsItems += response['MetricAlarms']
    response = client.describe_alarms(AlarmNamePrefix=prefix, MaxRecords=alarmMaxRecords, NextToken=response['NextToken']) if 'NextToken' in response else None

for alarm in alarmsItems:
    # Do something with the alarm
    print(response['MetricAlarms'])
```

The above will retrieve 10 records at a time, but can be anything up to 100.

Or more simply using the `paginate` method provided by boto3:

```
import boto3

# Create CloudWatch client
cloudwatch = boto3.client('cloudwatch')

# List alarms of insufficient data through the pagination interface
paginator = cloudwatch.get_paginator('describe_alarms')
for response in paginator.paginate(AlarmNamePrefix=prefix, MaxRecords=alarmMaxRecords):
    # Do something with the alarm
    print(response['MetricAlarms'])
```